# Svc File getting Downloaded instead browsing (Windows 8)

Tags: wcf, iis

In the below code i have a webconfig file in which i browse in iis only one svc file getting downloaded (ie) FileService.Other Svc File are browsing fine.Pls help me to overcome this issue.
I have Placed the webconfig please have look.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
      <!--<wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LargeFileHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">

          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647"
                        maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>

          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false"/>
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm=""/>

            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default"/>
          </security>


        </binding>        
      </wsHttpBinding>-->
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        </binding>


<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
         messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>


        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasGetConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
         textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
         messageEncoding="Text">
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        <security mode="None">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
        </security>
      </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasDataService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
       bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
       allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
          maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
            realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>

      <!--<netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasDataService" closeTimeout="00:00:05" openTimeout="00:00:05"
                 receiveTimeout="00:00:05" sendTimeout="00:00:05" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="524288" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="5242880">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>-->

    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:49478/GmasGetConfig.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasGetConfig"
                contract="GmasGetConfig.IGmasGetConfig" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasGetConfig" />
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:49478/GmasDataService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasDataService"
                contract="DataService.IGmasDataService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IGmasDataService" />

    </client>
    <services>
      <service name="GmasDistributor.FileService" behaviorConfiguration="GmasDistributor.FileService">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IFileTransfer" contract="GmasDistributor.IFileTransfer">

          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="GmasDistributor.FileService">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```